# WKB treatment for unstable particle

Tags: particle-physics, semiclassical

I was wondering if the WKB treatment of particles entering a potential (there is some reflection (R) and transmission (T) coefficient such that R+T =1) works only for stable particles. Essentially the WKB gives me a wave function of a state and the probability it will be reflected/transmitted across a potential.

What is I have an unstable intermediate particle, do I always need to use the stable final states?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but is too long for a comment.

Interesting question. I guess spontaneous fission would be an example, since it takes place by tunneling through a barrier. (The coordinate is some measure of the shape of the nucleus, leading to a saddle point and then scission.) People certainly do use WKB concepts to discuss fission, and the products are often unstable nuclei. So I think the answer is that it's at least sometimes OK.

My gut feeling would be that you'd run into problems if the half-life of the product was too short. The fission example would seem to indicate that it can be OK even if the half-life of the product is short compared to the rate of transmission. Perhaps there would be a problem if the half-life of the product was short compared to one over the frequency of assaults on the barrier (although such a thing is not actually very well-defined in examples like fission and alpha decay, since preformation of the product would violate the exclusion principle).

Comment: Hi Ben, 

thanks for your comment. If it is not too great a hassle, could you direct me to a good reference for this?

Comment: @SAMCRO: Reference for what part of it? Use of WKB concepts to discuss spontaneous fission? I think that would be discussed in any discussion of spontaneous fission, e.g., in standard textbooks, wikipedia, ...

Comment: right thanks I found this paper that looks at how good the approximation is: https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0375947414001961?token=A262C88460E9DBD8C1B6F254A1D160A3C946C84313B3FA086C0E3D072950D3214ACB5E96B001E228143A9146FDE58A7C